# How is intensity gain calculated, and how do I get a 9.9 in Classic Mode?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Specifically, how should I play in order to achieve a 9.9 intensity, while playing in Classic Mode?  I've seen different rounds end in different increments ranging from +0.5 - +0.8, but no explanation is given as to how those point increases are calculated. Specifically:

- Does your round score correlate to the intensity increase on the next round?
- Does using a ticket at the start of Classic affect the intensity gains?
- Is there a time limit on rounds, including the bonus, in order to net the most gain?
- Do I have to hit a certain amount of damage dealt, and conversely, is there a limit on how much damage I can take?

Some things I've noticed include having a teammate die (in co-cop Classic) can drastically cut the intensity gain down, sometimes resulting in only a gain of +0.1 - +0.2 intensity.

At one point I started a run with Snake, starting at the highest possible difficulty, and using a ticket. I did not have to restart any rounds, and I cleared most of the bonus points in the bonus round.  After all was said and done, I still ended at a 9.4, a far cry from the 9.9 needed for the achievement.

Comment: It’ll be interesting to get an explanation for why [this](https://youtu.be/6PjygGyCEFY) can get 9.9 so easily.

Answer (score 1):

The most important factors for intensity gain are:

- Clear rounds quickly
- Don't take much damage

I do not believe score or ticket usage are factors, and the bonus round does not matter at all.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0dAg0OAtgg) is an example run of reaching 9.9 before the final boss.

Comment: I'm not sure if time taken is a factor but maybe dps because I hit 9.9 pretty easily with Link by walling enemies out with projectiles before going for the kill.